# Using Clearance with API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I am currently using Clearance from Throughbot for my authentication. I am needing to add an API to my product and can't seem to find docs about using Clearance with an API. Is there a certain Header I can set that Clearance will check automatically and if not what can I use? I think I may be able to use [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/wiki/Authenticate-with-username).

Answer (score 2):

To get around this I ended up overriding the `authenticate` methods on the `ApplicationController` and the `User` model. It looks something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Clearance::Controller
  include Clearance::Authentication

  def authenticate(params)
    if request.headers['AUTH-TOKEN']
      return nil unless user = User.where(remember_token: request.headers['AUTH-TOKEN']).first
      sign_in user
    else
      User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
    end
  end
  #rest of class omitted for bevity
end
```

Then I subclasses `SessionsController` to override the `create` method like so:

```
class SessionsController < Clearance::SessionsController
  def create
    @user = authenticate(params)

    sign_in(@user) do |status|
      respond_to do |format|
        if status.success?
          format.html { redirect_back_or url_after_create }
          format.json { render json: @user, status: :ok }
        else
          format.html do
            flash.now.notice = status.failure_message
            render template: 'sessions/new', status: :unauthorized
          end
          format.json { render json: [errors: status.failure_message], status: :unauthorized }
        end
      end
    end
  end
  #rest of class omitted for bevity
end
```

Then all you have to do to test or use is set the requests `AUTH-TOKEN` header to the `users` remember token and you're all set.  I chose to use the remember token because it is updated whenever the user logs out. You may not want this to happen and could instead generate a `auth_token` field on your model and change the `where` to use the new field.